# How to get TOP 5 items by Sum(qty)?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to get TOP 5 items by Sum(qty), but if I use TOP in code below, I get msg: Top is not allowed in delete queries and reports.

My query:

```
TRANSFORM SUM(qty)
SELECT value1
FROM table1
Where value2 Between value3 AND value4
Group By value1
PIVOT value2;
```

Anyone have idea how to do it?

Comment: First, create a select query having your `TOP 5` clause. Next, use this as source in your crosstab query.

Comment: Yes, I think about this solution, but I don't know how to use value from one query to another.

Comment: You substitute it for the table.